# Android ExpandableListView разделители дочерних элементов

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Как можно включить разделители между дочерними элементами в ExpandableListView.
Пробую:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_16"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_16"
    android:id="@+id/expandable_shedul_filter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:childDivider="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top" />
```

но без результатов

Comment: попробуйте явно задать android:dividerHeight="1dp"

Comment: Так добавились разделители в группах, а мне нужно в дочерних элементах

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете написать свой **Layout** элемент, который будет получать adapter при добавлении элементов в **ExpandableListView** и в этом **Layout** вы можете добавить свой разделитель внизу

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#F2E6FF"/>
```